# How to make a current installation iso to install in different PCs?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

So, I have a pc with ubuntu 18.04 installed and several things already configured to it, and it is going to be replicated to other 30+ computers.

All the other pcs currently have windows installed, and my idea is to do a dual boot with this usb.

So far I have found systemback utility, with it I have created a .iso file but when I start another pc with it using a usb, it shows some options for boot live installer,

but on next screen it doesnt show like a fresh ubuntu install a way to configure how big is the partition and continue. I can't proceed.

It shows several sda partitions and I can't resize them to install the iso I created. I even (on windows using easeus partition master) created a 50gb partition to see if doing that I could install on it, still can't do it.

Any ideas how can I finish this? Or is there an easier method?

Comment: Depending upon your skills, resources, and customizations, PXE booting, a Preseed file, or a postinstall script might be easier.

Comment: why PXE booting? isn't it to initialize pcs throughout the network? I am not looking for this. It is just a way to make an iso with configured ubuntu and then I can install using a usb flash but maintaining the windows in the other PCs.